# How to create and return a text Array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, carousel

So I'm making a carousel with images and would like to also include corresponding text. Have successfully mapped through my images array however my text array not so successful. It's 100% a syntax error because I'm shooting in the dark here. How should I be going about this instead?

```js
TEXT/IMAGE ARRAY
   import image1 from "../img/breakfast.jpg" ;
import image2 from "../img/burger.jpg";
import image3 from "../img/curry.jpg";
import image4 from "../img/dessert.jpg";
import image5 from "../img/italian.jpg";
import image6 from "../img/kebab.jpg";
import image7 from "../img/sushi.jpg";
import image8 from "../img/pizza.jpg";
import image9 from "../img/roast.jpg";
import image10 from "../img/greek.jpg";
import image11 from "../img/healthy.jpg";

export default [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5,
image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, image11 ]




const cuisine1 = "Breakfast";
const cuisine2 = "Burger";
const cuisine3 = "Indian";
const cuisine4 = "Dessert";
const cuisine5 = "Italian";
const cuisine6 = "Kebab";
const cuisine7 = "Sushi";
const cuisine8 = "Pizza";
const cuisine9 = "Roast";
const cuisine10 = "Greek";
const cuisine11 = "Healthy";

export const cuisineString=[
{
  cuisine: cuisine1
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine2
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine3
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine4
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine5
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine6
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine7
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine8
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine9
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine10
},
{
  cuisine: cuisine11
}
  ] 

CAROUSEL FUNCTIONALITY
import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import {useRef, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import image from "../img/carouselArray"
import {cuisineString} from "../img/carouselArray"
import "../style/home.css";

export const Carousel = () => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const carousel = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(carousel.current.scrollWidth, carousel.current.of
        setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth)
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="carouselContainer">
        
        <motion.div ref={carousel} className="carousel" whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}>
        <motion.div drag="x"
        dragConstraints= {{ right: 0, left: -width}}
        className ="innerCarousel">
                {image.map(image =>{
                    return(
                      <motion.div className="item" key={image}>
                          {/* <h5>Cuisine</h5> */}
                          <a href=""><img className="itemImg" src={image} alt="Cuisine"/></a>
                      </motion.div>
                    );
                })}
                 {cuisineString.map(index =>{
                    return(
                      <motion.div className="item" key={index}>
                          <h5>{index}</h5>
                          {/* <a href=""><img className="itemImg" src={image} alt="Cuisine"/></a> */}
                      </motion.div>
                    );
                })}
            </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
    
    
        </div>
        
    );
    }
```

UPDATE: Found a solution will insert code snippet below

```js
Two Seperate arrays for images and strings: 

import image1 from "../img/chinese.jpg" ;
import image2 from "../img/burger.jpg";
import image3 from "../img/italian.jpg";
import image4 from "../img/indian.jpg";
import image5 from "../img/kebab.jpg";
import image6 from "../img/sushi.jpg";



export default [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5,
image6]


const cuisine1 = "Chinese";
const cuisine2 = "American";
const cuisine3 = "Italian";
const cuisine4 = "Indian";
const cuisine5 = "Turkish";
const cuisine6 = "Japanese";

export const cuisineString=[
    {
      cuisine: cuisine1
    },
    {
      cuisine: cuisine2
    },
    {
      cuisine: cuisine3
    },
    {
      cuisine: cuisine4
    },
    {
      cuisine: cuisine5
    },
    {
      cuisine: cuisine6
    }
  ] 
  
Mapped through them seperalty, styled in css so that titles appeared above images. Anchor tag now working on the image. 

import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import {useRef, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import image from "../img/carouselArray"
import {cuisineString} from "../img/carouselArray"
import "../style/home.css";

export const Carousel = () => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const carousel = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(carousel.current.scrollWidth, carousel.current.of
        setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth)
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="carouselContainer">
        
        <motion.div ref={carousel} className="carousel" whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}}>
        <motion.div drag="x"
        dragConstraints= {{ right: 0, left: -width}}
        className ="innerCarousel">
            <div className="caroselRow">
                {image.map(image =>{
                    return(
                      <motion.div className="item" key={image}>
                          {/* <h5>Cuisine</h5> */}
                          <button className="btnImage"><a href=""><img className="itemImg" src={image} alt="Cuisine"/></a></button>
                      </motion.div>
                      
                    );
                })}
                </div>
                <div className="caroselRow">
                 {cuisineString.map(({cuisine})=>{
                    return(
                      <motion.div className="itemTitle">
                         <p className="itemTitleReturn" key={cuisine}>{cuisine}</p>
                      </motion.div>
                    );
                })}
                </div>
            </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
    
    
        </div>
        
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
                {images.map((image , index) =>{
                return(
                  <motion.div className="item" key={image}>
                      {cuisine[index]}
                      <a href="/"><img className="itemImg" src={image} alt="Cuisine"/></a>
                  </motion.div>
                );
            })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Instead of doing like this, create an array of objects. For example

```
const carouselArray = [
  {
    "image": image1,
    "cuisine": cuisine1
  },
  {
    "image": image2,
    "cuisine": cuisine2
  }{
    "image": image3,
    "cuisine": cuisine3
  }{
    "image": image4,
    "cuisine": cuisine4
  }
]
```

Then

```
{carouselArray.map((item , index) =>{
                return(
                  <motion.div className="item" key={item.image}>
                      {item.cuisine}
                      <a href="/"><img className="itemImg" src={item.image} alt="Cuisine"/></a>
                  </motion.div>
                );
```

Comment: okay cool thank you looks a lot better. Sorry to be dim I'm new to all this but would I no longer need too define what I would like the cuisine too be with <p> tags?

Comment: just because this way I'm still getting "'cuisine1' is not defined   no-undef",

just tried with the <p> tags and still get this hmm

Comment: I also get:   item, image and carousel as undefined

Comment: Update the code so that I can see what change you made.

Comment: move all `const cuisine1=''` outside array

Comment: done plus tried mapping images and strings separately, edited updates, nothing yet

Comment: let me create a demo for you in codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sanderson-hf1cpw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you! Couldn't get to work with this but it helped with figuring out how to fix it, updated the code with the solution I found